# Hage-che: -ㄹ쏜가 [or -으ㄹ쏜가] interrogative form examples

Tags: grammar, speech-levels, sentence-endings

I am watching a lot of Korean dramas and it always nice to hear different speech levels.

I wanted to frain members over here on the ending: 으ㄹ쏜가

**Could you please give me some examples and translation you have come accross that could help explain the meaning better ?** I plan to add it to an anki deck.

Naver gives the following examples:

> 나의 마음을 아는 이 누구일쏜가.

> *My translation:* Who could possibly know my heart.

> 뉘라서 천하장사를 이길쏜가.

> *My translation:* Who could beat the world champion.

> 내가 비록 자네에게 화가 났으나 내가 자네 험담을 할쏜가?

> *My translation:* Even though I am angry with you, how could I gossip about you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-ㄹ쏜가 is an old-style form of -겠는가

which means a strong negative question.

Your examples and translations are correct.